# html select list - display seleted value when size is 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have a html select list that I am using to display many options.

I have the size of the select to `10` and I am using `autofocus`.

**How do I dcisplay the select list so that the selected option is displayed when the page loads, even if the selected option is not in the 1st 10 options**, like this:

[image]

Currently, when the page loads, the select list is displayed as follows (option 19 is selected, but not displayed):

[image]

Here is my select list code:

```
<select id="id_preview_style_select" name="preview_style" title="Preview Style" size="10" autofocus>
    ....
    ....
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add **selected** and **focus** attribute to the desired option tag

```
<select id="id_preview_style_select" name="preview_style" title="Preview Style" size="10" autofocus>
    ....

    <option value="10" selected focus> 20 </option>

    ....
</select>
```

check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPJ4S/67/)

Comment: He said it's already selected but the list is not scrolled to the 19th item.

Comment: ah! so very simple! Thanks.